# Should it be easier for employers to see your information once you have allowed it?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I have received messages from potential employers asking for my contact information or a copy of my resume after I have indicated that I am interested and allowed them to see my contact information. What does it look like for them at that point? Why isn't my contact information readily available along with the option to download a copy of my profile as a PDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks the same for you as it does for them, in the header details for the message.

[image]

This is shown by hovering over it, much like gmail.  I'll bring this up today and see if we can come up with something more obvious for this.

On the employer side, there is a direct link to download the profile right from the message thread.

[image]

I'm afraid I cannot think of something more obvious for this one however.

Comment: Cool! Hovering for the contact information isn't immediately apparent, I guess, but I agree that the giant blue button is pretty obvious.